# System.Net.WebClient not throwing error during UploadString to invalid url?

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

Given this code, I expected an exception to happen, but [System.Net.WebClient.UploadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0645045y) returns an empty string into `result`.

I'm obviously overlooking something, but what?

```
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

[TestClass()]
public class WebClientTests
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void WebClientUploadStringToInvalidUrlTest()
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
        var result =  webClient.UploadString("{{foo-bar}}", "snafu");
        Assert.IsTrue(string.IsNullOrEmpty(result));
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
    public void WebClientUploadStringToNullUrlTest()
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
        string url = null;
        var result = webClient.UploadString(url, "snafu");
        Assert.IsTrue(string.IsNullOrEmpty(result));
    }

}
```

*edit*: as [per suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082706/system-net-webclient-not-throwing-error-during-uploadstring-to-invalid-url?noredirect=1#comment37140208_24082706) by [hanno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/964955/hanno) added a `null` test as well, and this throws an `ArgumentNullException` which I kind of expected.

Comment: Just to be sure: This test passes exactly as written?! Update: It does.

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0645045y(v=vs.110).aspx) it should throw an exception. Does it throw if you pass null into the method?

Comment: I wonder what if a different URL is entered; perhaps that form in the URI does something odd? (trying...)

Comment: Hmm... just ran `string res = cl.UploadString("blah", "adsfkasd");` and I also got no exception, and an empty string. But `string res = cl.UploadString("http://blah", "adsfkasd");` gave me a WebException for could not be resolved.

Comment: Also, for the first code I ran, the `ResponseHeaders` collection after `UploadString()` completed contained `Content-Length` and `Content-Type` properties, but they were also empty.

Comment: @Hanno then it throws an exception, see edit.

Comment: Running it inside of ASP.NET app threw exception *"Access to the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\{{foo-bar}}' is denied."*

Comment: I have got the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only possible to answer this by looking at internal implementation details.

In preparation the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient) class tries to build an real [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri) from the string you provided in that overload to [UploadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144236).

The code roughly looks like this in the 4.0 framework:

```
 if (!Uri.TryCreate(path, UriKind.Absolute, out address))
 {
      return new Uri(Path.GetFullPath(path));
 }
```

The [TryCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131572) returns [false](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67bxt5ee.aspx) for your non [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier) conforming path so it falls back to creating an `Uri` for the [Path.GetFullPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath) of your string, which returns an `Uri` with a [file:// scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).

Internally the `WebClient` uses [WebRequest.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0aa3d588) to obtain a [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest) that is capable of handling the given [scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme). In your case a [FileWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.filewebrequest) will be returned (due to the scheme being `file://`)

Stripping all checks and internal plumbing the following simplified call sequence is executed after the `Uri` is obtained:

```
        var fwr = (FileWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(new Uri(Path.GetFullPath(path)));
        fwr.Method ="POST";
        var us = fwr.GetRequestStream();
        var upload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("snafu");
        us.Write(upload,0,upload.Length);
        us.Close();
        var sr = new StreamReader(fwr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Which doesn't throw an exception and returns an empty string.

Your assumption *"I expect this to throw an exception"* is wrong.

Comment: Is it a `FileWebRequest` or `FtpWebRequest`? And if it is indeed a `FileWebRequest`: shouldn't the upload fail, as the file does not exist and the upload location is invalid? Or does it upload to some current directory? (I'm not behind a PC for quite a few hours, so I cannot test this soon).

Comment: It is a FileWebRequest for sure. I can't answer why it succeeds, only the designers of that code can answer that.

Comment: OK. I'll update your answer to fix that and a few more typos.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers I went ahead and fixed the most obvious ones (it was late when I wrote that answer) ... feel free to fix anything I overlooked...

Comment: Thanks. For now we've limited the allowed schemes to http and https. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Official_IANA-registered_schemes

Comment: I got around it by using: !Url.ToLower().StartsWith("http")