# How to send GET/POST request programmatically to simple ASPX page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, webclient

I use following code to post `querystring`

```
string URI = "http://somewebsite.com/default.aspx";
string myParameters = "param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3";
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
   wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
   string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
}
```

But somehow `default.aspx` does not accept that post call.

The point is when I manually in browser go to `http://somewebsite.com/default.aspx` all code there is working fine.

My questions is following what do I am missing here to archive the same result  when I open page manually as I do it with **WebClient**?

Thank you in advance!

P.S. 1

I just tried to use GET method to that URL and it has no effect also. How is it possible?
What is difference between manual navigation to page and sending GET/POST?

P.S. 2

I even tried this

```
wc.Headers["Accept"] = "application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*";
            wc.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; MDDC)";
```

and and **Load** event of **Default.aspx** is not hiting. :(

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to basically navigate to http://somewebsite.com/default.aspx but also add on the parameters param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3 into that string?

Comment: @sr28 No, it is not. The page when I navigate manually is writing a simple text file. So it works fine when i use browser. Now I need to "open" this page within asp.net event when open some other page I would like to do it. And I assumed to use WebClient but it seems like it has no impact to the target page that's odd.

Comment: So you're saying that if you manually type in http://somewebsite.com/default.aspx to a browser that works fine, but when you use it as a parameter in UploadString() it doesn't work?

Comment: @sr28 Exactly it is. I donno why...

Comment: So what error are you getting?

Comment: @sr28 No errors at all.

Comment: @sr28 In the target page i have 1 line of the code ` protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { WriteLog("sometext");  }`

Comment: Are you saying that `WriteLog` doesn't do anything, and you've verified that? Just making sure, because _whereever_ it is you have the code above will simply `POST` (what does `HtmlResult` contain?). I mocked your code and it's fine for me (obtained result from target of POST and wrote the result in the _originating_ page).

Comment: @EdSF Yes that is the problem I have got. I already checked all possible options with ` webClient.UploadValues(URI, values);
` and ` WebRequest.Create` and no joy. So I am wondering why Those aproaches are not giving the same result as if I open page manually? Have I specify something in headers of the request?

Comment: Copied your code almost verbatim (except WriteLog of course), works fine for me. If you step through debug, it doesn't even hit `Load` of default.aspx?

Comment: @EdSF Yest `Load` of `default.aspx` is not hitings at all. That the issue. But manually it works fine.

Comment: @EdSF One thing I just found is  that I cannot get `HtmlResult `  and code even goes out of to WebException /Exception... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082706/system-net-webclient-not-throwing-error-during-uploadstring-to-invalid-url

Comment: _"What is difference between manual navigation to page and sending GET/POST?"_ - see for yourself, for example using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: Then that link you provided should give you the answer - it's not actually sending any request to the target because of some exception...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that comment is correct one

> "What is difference between manual navigation to page and sending
>   GET/POST?" - see for yourself, for example using Fiddler. – 
>   CodeCaster

I checked all requests with Fiddler and found that there is code of base page class that redirects to Index page. So Load event is never happened.

Answer (score 0):

From your description of what you want to achieve, I think you may have chosen the wrong `WebClient` method. Instead of `UploadString`, try `DownloadString`:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
  string HtmlResult = wc.DownloadString("http://somewebsite.com/default.aspx?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3");
}
```

Comment: I just checked it and it seems like working wrong... It just does not return any data and even go to the next line of the code also it ignores exceptions.That is odd.